# Route not displayed after login with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-ui-router, router

My application should contain two areas, the admin (in which we call iwti) and the 'retaguarda', this second is already working normally, however when I access the route `/iwti` the layout inside the `<router-outlet>` does not appear. I removed the login guard and accessed the route directly and loaded without the layout part. It is also worth informing that I have an idle timer on which the user displaces, however when it will redirect to the login page, the system displays a route:

```
Error "Can not find primary outlet to load 'LoginComponent'".
```

I do not know if I'm doing the areas change correctly, but I'll put the code down.

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
export const rotasPrincipais: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
]
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-iwti *ngIf="ambiente.isIWTIUserAuthentication">
</app-iwti>

<app-retaguarda *ngIf="!ambiente.isIWTIUserAuthentication">
```

**iwti.routing.module.ts**

```
const iwtiRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'iwti', component: IwtiDashboardComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
    { path: 'iwti/funcionario', component: IwtiFuncionarioComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] }
]
```

After logging in the user is directed through the `router.navigate (['iwti'])`.

**iwti.component.html**

```
<header>
    <div [hidden]="!ambiente.isAuthenticated">
        <app-iwtinavbar></app-iwtinavbar> <!--It appears normally when logged in-->
    </div>
</header>
<div class="container" [hidden]="!ambiente.isAuthenticated">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet> <!--I believe the problem is this, if I give a name to the outlet and refer to the file where I declare the route, it says it can not find a route with this name.-->
</div>
```

**structure**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app.component.html needs a router-outlet
In the main component for each module that does routing, you'll need a router-outlet. So in your case it looks like app.module and iwti.module both do routing. Since your IWTI already has a  it knows where to render your child routes, but your app.module does not.

The below should fix your issue, but you'll also need to make sure the routes are setup properly. Make sure your iwti-routing.module calls forChildren instead of forRoot.

change app.component.html to

```
<app-iwti *ngIf="ambiente.isIWTIUserAuthentication">
</app-iwti>

<app-retaguarda *ngIf="!ambiente.isIWTIUserAuthentication">
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: This did not solve the problem, I have to tell you that inside each of these two components has the <router-outlet>, that is, always one of the two is loaded. Apart from that I also said that everything inside the <app-rear> tag works, all routes are 100% there, the problem is that it's pretty much the same code on the <app-iwti> side but it does not work in this case.

Comment: I just tried to comment a <router-outlet> in the rear and the iwti opens again, but with bugs, after being redirected to the login page when the idle time count ends the outlet router is not modified on the login page . I think the assembly is being made wrong, because I'm having to have two <router-outlet>

Comment: Please setup a plunkr example with your code and I'll take a look

Comment: I'm working on your idea and trying to find a solution. I've already managed to make the routes work so I'll put the answer right. Now I have some places that are bug, because the idle timer is not zeroing as it should and also has a bug when loading the dropdown javascript, I believe it is because of * ngIf, but I have not yet found a solution. If you can help me with this too, thank you.

Comment: Claro, glad the other issue is resolved. If you post the new question in a new post and link it here I'll take a look.

Comment: I've already encountered the problem again, but I can not find an ideal solution. The *ngIf does not load the html, so if I use [hidden] instead of using the *ngIf it works, but it is vulnerable, just remove the hidden html tag that will be there, there is an answer to these questions here already I have not posted yet, but if you know of a solution before I need to create one more question, it is best. If you can, you can put the link there.

Comment: I'm sorry Luis but I don't understand. If this is a new question, please put it in a new post here on StackOverflow and link to it, then I will take a look.